# toString error, cannot resolve method toString()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to convert a double into a string for displaying purposes but I get an error saying "Cannot resolve method "toString()"

I tested printing a string and it works, however when I try to pass a double my app crashes

```
void calcTheTip(Double tipPercentage) {

    //getting the total bill (without the tip):
    double billTotal = Double.valueOf(billTotalEditText.getText().toString());

    //calculating the tip percentage:
    double tipTotal = billTotal * tipPercentage;

    //displaying the tip:
    tipTotalTextView.setText(tipTotal.toString());

    //calculate total:
    double total = tipTotal + billTotal;

    //display the total:
    totalAmountTextView.setText(tipTotal.toString(total));
}
```

I expect it to display to total in the app,
so far the total was a double but I need it to be a string for displaying purposes.

Comment: `Double.toString(tipTotal)`

Answer (score 4):

This wont even compile, as you can't call methods on a primitive (`tipTotal` is a `double`).

Use `String.valueOf(tipTotal)` instead.

Answer (score 3):

That's because `tipTotal` is a primitive type `double`.

Use one of the following methods,

```
"" +tipTotal;
Double.toString(tipTotal);
String.valueOf(tipTotal);
new Double(tipTotal).toString();
String.format("%f", tipTotal) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call a method on primitive types like `double`, `int`, `float` in Java. You have bunch of options to put inside `setText` method

- `Double.toString(tipTotal)`
- `String.valueOf(tipTotal)`
- `tipTotal + ""`

Answer (score 0):

Method toString() haven't arguments.
If you want print your result: totalAmountTextView.setText(String.valueOf(total))

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and I found out why!

You should use Double when you are creating `tipTotal` (double is not the same as Double) since Double is a class that offers you the method `toString()`.

So you should declare `tipTotal` as such:

```
Double tipTotal;
String str = tipTotal.toString();
```